# I am having trouble accesing the ID in R.id its not working

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, ide, r.id

I am having trouble accesing the ID in R.id I have an image on imgur showing what I'm talking about . I don't know why it is happening I am using Intellij for an IDE .

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v33wR.jpg

Any idea what the problem is ?

**UPDATED**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="main.java.com.mycompany.myapp">

    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        />
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
        />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <activity
            android:name="main.java.com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data 
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable"
                />


        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I can post up code if needed .

Comment: Show us your manifest.xml

Comment: I have added the manifest.xml

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229091/eclipse-not-recognizing-r-id-with-android

Comment: I don't belive it is a duplicate. Case is in mine is that it had the squiggle underneath the id and not the R

Comment: any idea why ??